# Color codes for echo don't work when running a script over ssh

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh

all.

I have the following exemple code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[\033[01;32m  green  \033[01;37m]"
echo "[\033[01;31m  red  \033[01;37m]"
```

When I run this script locally, I get the correct output color.

But if I copy to another host over scp and run it with "ssh avadmin@10.224.1.6 "sudo sh color-test.sh"" the script will print the code instead of the color.

Should I have any considerations when running script remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of

```
echo '\033'
```

Depends on the implementation and/or the environment.

With UNIX-compliant implementations, it outputs a ESC character followed by NL, in some others, it outputs `\033` followed by NL. Some support a `-e` option for those `\033` escape sequences to be expanded.

Your script has a `#! /bin/bash` she-bang, but you're running the script as `sh the-script`, so `sh` interprets it, not `bash`.

On most systems, `bash`'s `echo` builtin doesn't expand `\x` sequences by default. It only does so when the `xpg_echo` option is enabled or by using the `-e` option (unless both the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options have been enabled).

Probably your local `sh` implementation is a UNIX-compliant  one in that regard (like `dash`, or `bash` compiled with the `xpg_echo` option enabled by default), but the one on the remote server is not (like `bash`).

If you want a portable and reliable behaviour, [use `printf` instead](/q/65803):

```
printf '[\33[01;32m  green  \33[01;37m]\n'
printf '[\33[01;31m  red  \33[01;37m]\n'
```

Comment: Further reading is, of course, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP, it's already referenced in the answer.

Comment: So it is.  I failed to spot that.